# changing opacity of text and a background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency

https://okbinteractive.studio/

Above is a website, where I'm trying to use the same text/background fill format.

As you can see, they've got a background with its opacity down low, but the text on top is filled with the background at its normal opacity.

I can't work out how to do this in Photoshop

Answer (score 1):

Open an image you want to use as the background image, something colourful.

1. Type some text on top
2. In the layers panel select and duplicate the background layer <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, then click and drag it to the top of the layers.
3. Clip the top layer to the text layer by <kbd>Alt / Option</kbd>+clicking on the line between both layer thumbnails. The Duplicate layer thumbnail will show with a downward pointing arrow indicating it is clipped to the text layer below.
4. Add a new layer above the background layer and fill it white, reduce the layer opacity in the layers panel until you get the amount of fading you want.

Example

[image]

Comment: Brilliant!! Thank you very much

Comment: Can the same be done for videos???
On the website i linked in my first post, they have a video which plays in the fill of two letters.... Is this achievable in photoshop/other abode apps???
Kind regards

Comment: Probably possible in Adobe After Effects. I don't know how to use it, sorry.  There's a [Video Production Stack Exchange](https://video.stackexchange.com/) for video editing quesitons.  Don't post video editing questions here on GDSE because they're off-topic.